# Expected type X but passed X | undefined | null even with check

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this piece of code:

```
if (!context) {
  alertStore.SET_GLOBAL_ALERT({
    color: "red",
    text: "Cannot get context of chart",
    show: true,
    loading: false,
  });
  return;
}
let sets = usersDatapoints.map(({ data }) => {
  return getDatasets(data, context, gradientHeight, borderWidth).consumption
})
```

My problem is at `getDatasets`. It complains about `context`.

My function `getDatasets` expects an `CanvasRenderingContext2D` but receives an `CanvasRenderingContext2D | undefined | null`

I even did an check before `if(!context) { ... return }` but it still complains about.

Why is typescript not able to get the right type here?

Comment: if you hover over the type of `context`  at the original if or further down what is it?

Comment: Define `context` as `const`. Otherwise TypeScript will assume that some code might change its value back to `undefined` between the `if` condition and when the `map` callback is called (which might be asynchronous, for all TS knows).

Comment: The rule of thumb is: always use `const` apart from the situation you just can't.